# How to force caching with HttpsURLConnection and HttpResponseCache on Android?

Tags: java, android, httpsurlconnection, httpresponsecache

I have the method below to request pages from wiktionary.org, the problem is that the server is returning `Cache-control => private, must-revalidate, max-age=0` in the headers, which is preventing `HttpsURLConnection` from storing the requests.

Is there a way to force then caching of those pages?

```
protected static synchronized String getUrlContent(String url) throws ApiException {
    if (sUserAgent == null) {
        throw new ApiException("User-Agent string must be prepared");
    }

    try {
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", sUserAgent);
        //connection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-stale");
        //connection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=3600");
        //connection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "only-if-cached");

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
            throw new ApiException("Invalid response from server: " + responseCode);
        }

        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream content = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // Read response into a buffered stream
        int readBytes = 0;
        while ((readBytes = inputStream.read(sBuffer)) != -1) {
            content.write(sBuffer, 0, readBytes);
        }

        HttpResponseCache cache = HttpResponseCache.getInstalled();
        if (cache != null) {
            Log.w("!!!", "Cache hit count: " + cache.getHitCount());
            //connection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=3600");
            Log.w("!!!", "Cache-Control: " + connection.getHeaderField("Cache-Control"));
            //cache.put(new URI(url), connection);
        }

        // Return result from buffered stream
        return new String(content.toByteArray());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ApiException("Problem communicating with API", e);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Still not able to get a cache hit with [okhttp interceptors](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors#rewriting-responses)

```
static private OkHttpClient client;
static private Cache cache;

public static OkHttpClient getClient() {
    if (client == null) {
        File cacheDirectory = new File(App.getInstance().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath(), "HttpCache");
        cache = new Cache(cacheDirectory, 1024 * 1024);
        client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cache(cache)
                .addInterceptor(REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR).build();
    }
    return client;
}

/** Dangerous interceptor that rewrites the server's cache-control header. */
private static final Interceptor REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR = new Interceptor() {
    @Override public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                .header("Cache-Control", "max-age=60")
                .build();
    }
};

protected static synchronized String getUrlContent(String url) throws ApiException {
    try {

        OkHttpClient httpClient = getClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();

        Log.w("!!!", "hitCount: " + cache.hitCount());

        return response.body().string();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ApiException("Problem communicating with API", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not cache them yourself, above the layer of the HTTP requests (e.g., in  your repository)?

Comment: @CommonsWare If I change the domain to some other site that supports caching then I'll need to check for a cache hit in order to not cache the data myself. It seems neither `HttpsURLConnection` nor `HttpResponseCache` has a way to check that. Also, I was thinking maybe I could change the headers in the connection object and store it in the cache like so `cache.put(uri, connection);` but it seems it's not possible.

Comment: "If I change the domain to some other site that supports caching then I'll need to check for a cache hit in order to not cache the data myself" -- or, tell the HTTP stack to not cache, and handle it in the application layer. I don't know if `HttpsURLConnection` offers that, though OkHttp does. It's possible there's an OkHttp configuration that handles what you're aiming for, though I didn't see one in a quick scan.

Comment: @CommonsWare updated my question with okhttp but still can't get a cache hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `addNetworkInterceptor` instead of `addInterceptor` to rewrite cache-control when initializing your OKHttpClient.

Comment: Can I put the `User-Agent` in the same interceptor, or do I need a second one, and add it with `addInterceptor` instead?

Comment: Why do you need an interceptor for `user-agent`? Just add it when you build your request.

Comment: I see, you mean `Request.Builder().addHeader()`...that would do, thanks.